# My sd card is not connecting to my Android phone

Tags: sd-card

My brother purchased a new sd card for my Android phone (it's an alcatel onetouch yh I know it's old) to increase memory. Its a 8 gb card, but my phone still says low on space when I try to download any apps.There was no notification telling me that an sd caed was inserted either. I tried selecting sd card and it shows 8 gb available but I still can't download apps. Then I switched to internal memory just to see if that would help but nothing happened. Plz someone help!

Answer (score 0):

The information provided is less.. so I'm assuming that the sd card is detected and is working and.. you're trying to download apps from google play store..

Lemme explain... The apps downloaded are automatically stored in your internal storage so even if you sd card has space available it won't be used.

What you can do for this..
try to delete useless stuffs and free up space from your internal storage (I'd recommend you to download Files by Google for this)
and copy all the videos from your internal storage to the sd card..

HOPE IT HELPS.. (^_^)

Comment: Thank you but I tried that a million times and it wasn't working I got a little frustrated and factory reset my phone and now it works wonderfully but again thank you for taking the time out of your day to try and help me